# I want to create an Android Gallery with different size columns

Tags: android, gridview, gallery, android-glide, subsampling

I want to create a Photo Gallery with two columns, like shown in the image here

[image]

The image must be subsampled and also keep her aspect ratio.
This is the custom transformation that subsamples the image:

```
  public ImageCustomTransformation(Context context, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    super(context);
    this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
    this.maxHeight = maxHeight;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {

    int targetWidth, targetHeight;
    double aspectRatio;

    if (toTransform.getWidth() > toTransform.getHeight()) {
        targetWidth = maxWidth;
        aspectRatio = (double) toTransform.getHeight() / (double) toTransform.getWidth();
        targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
    } else {
        targetHeight = maxHeight;
        aspectRatio = (double) toTransform.getWidth() / (double) toTransform.getHeight();
        targetWidth = (int) (targetHeight * aspectRatio);
    }

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(toTransform, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
    if (result != toTransform) {
        toTransform.recycle();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the code for the GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_photos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/set_photo_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/set_photo_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Upload Photo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the item for the GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/and`enter code here`roid"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_gallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></ImageView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

To load the images I am using Glide Library, and I pass it the Context and the dimensions to subsample(transform) the images. The result is not the one I imagined.
Can anyone help me figure out how to accomplish the layout from the example image above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for AsymmetricGridView or QuiltViewLibrary, these examples might be useful.